# Launching Android Studio find the exception that com.intellij.openapi.vfs.InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file:

Tags: android-studio

Accessing invalid virtual file: file:///Users/zhanghuagang/AndroidCode/BloodPresure/patient/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/homehealth/patient/R.java; original:515343; found:-
com.intellij.openapi.vfs.InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file: file:///Users/zhanghuagang/AndroidCode/BloodPresure/patient/app/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/homehealth/patient/R.java; original:515343; found:-
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.getFileId(PersistentFSImpl.java:319)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.mustReloadContent(PersistentFSImpl.java:596)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.getLength(PersistentFSImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileSystemEntry.getLength(VirtualFileSystemEntry.java:244)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl.reloadFromDisk(FileDocumentManagerImpl.java:624)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl.contentsChanged(FileDocumentManagerImpl.java:609)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.fireAfter(BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.after(BulkVirtualFileListenerAdapter.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:377)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:364)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:343)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.after(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.processEvents(PersistentFSImpl.java:774)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEventsInWriteAction(RefreshSessionImpl.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEvents(RefreshSessionImpl.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: have you tried this ?? File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: and add some code and explanation so we can better understand.

Comment: Not  code , finding the exception when I start  the AS. But it isn't problem that run project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

" File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart"
is OK.